# zsh: command not found: sanity

Tags: node.js, npm, sanity

Hi I have installed the Sanity CLI using:

npm install -g @sanity/cli

However when I try sanity init, I get:

zsh: command not found: sanity

it does work when I use:

npx @sanity/cli init

However when I try to use sanity start I get the command not found again.

Comment: Run `npm list -g` see if there is sanity in the list

Answer (score 2):

As Tushar mentioned, give `npm list -g --depth 0` a try and ensure `@sanity/cli` appears. To get your project going, you can continue to prefix commands with `npx`—`npx sanity start`—until the global package installation is resolved. You may also want to try running `npm uninstall -g @sanity/cli` and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled then got it to start working but when I ran `npm list -g` `@sanity/cli` wasn't found and if I run the `npx sanity start` again it says `zsh: command not found:`